# Android Architecture Component - Prevent @OnLifecycleEvent when launching camera Intent

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

I implemented 2 LifecycleEvents Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE and Lifecycle.Event.ON_START now these get triggered whenever I launch the camera Intent (which is logical in some way). Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Try removing the lifecycle observer when you're launching the camera intent, and re-add the observer afterwards, or add a boolean flag to differentiate the events

Comment: Was hoping for a cleaner solution, my app is rather large and has a lot of intents firing up (adding contacts, selecting picture from galery, opening webbrowser,...). But yeah I added a boolean flag, thanks!